# Unable to parse query string when filtering data in Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to see what values in column A of sheet 2 are not present in column A of sheet 1

Since I am new to Google sheets, I came up with the following query:

```
=query(sheet2!A:A," select * where A is not null and A not matches (select A from sheet1)")
```

But the error shown buy google sheets is:

```
Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: PARSE_ERROR: Encountered " <ID> "A "" at line 1, column 35. Was expecting one of: "(" ... "(" ...
```

The clause `and A not matches (select A from sheet1)` seems to have some issue and I can't pin point the exact issue. Please help.

Comment: the "(select A from sheet1)" won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also try:

```
=FILTER(A:A,ISERROR(XMATCH(A:A,Sheet1!A:A)),A:A<>"")
```

- 

[image]